# Converting string into datetime within Django modelform

Tags: django, datetime, django-forms

I would like to accept natural language strings into a DateTime field, on a form generated by a Django ModelForm.  I found [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime/22128786#22128786), which explains how to convert the input string into a DateTime object.  (In this case, I'm using timestring for the conversion, instead of strptime as suggested in the answers, because I want to handle input like 'tomorrow'.)   But I can't figure out where code this like should be placed within the ModelForm code.  If the conversion code is placed in `form_valid`, it never gets run, because `is_python` runs first and complains that the text input is not a DateTime.  When I override `is_python`, I get an error that I think comes from some kind of recursive loop.

Relevant code:

**models.py**

```
class Widget(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    widget_date = models.DateTimeField
```

**forms.py**

```
from timestring import Date

class NaturalDateField(forms.DateField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return none
        return Date(value, tz=timezone.get_current_timezone())

class WidgetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    widget_date = NaturalDateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ['name', 'widget_date']
```

**views.py**

```
class WidgetUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Widget
    form_class = WidgetForm
```

The error on submit is `Invlid date string >>`.  Tracing the code shows that the initial input string converts correctly (to something like '2014-12-26 00:00:00-08:00'), but then the validate() function from site-packages/django/forms/fields.py runs and that goes back into the timestring package for some reason and tries to run `def __eq__(self, other):` from Date.py, which I think tries to run Date(other), which fails since other is blank.

What is the best method to accept a text string in a ModelForm and then convert it to a field-specific string such as DateTime to be saved in the database?

Comment: What is `Date` in your `to_python` method?

Comment: Date is a natural-language parsing class from Timestring.  Added import to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that project, your code will return a `timestring.Date` object, which Django doesn't know what to do with. You probably just need to get the `date` value from there:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if not value:
        return none
    parsed_date = Date(value, tz=timezone.get_current_timezone())
    return parsed_date.date
```

Comment: That worked - also, I had to add in exception handling so that form validation would still work:

    try:
            parsed_date = Date(value, tz=timezone.get_current_timezone())
        except:
            raise ValidationError("Could not understand: %s" % value)

        return parsed_date.date

Answer (score 0):

Try reusing [builtin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1330) django date parsing methods:

```
class NaturalDateField(forms.DateField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(NaturalDateField, self).to_python(value)
        return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())
```